# How to show divisoral sheaf is rank one?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, birational-geometry

For a Weil divisor $D$ on a normal variety $X$, the sheaf $\mathcal{O}_{X}(D)$ associated to $D$ is defined by
$$
\Gamma\left(V, \mathcal{O}_{X}(D)\right):=\left\{f \in \mathbb{C}(X)^{*}|(f)|_{V}+\left.D\right|_{V} \geq 0\right\} \cup\{0\}
$$
for each open subset $V \subset X$, where $(f)$ is the principal divisor given by a rational function $f \in \mathbb{C}(X)^{*}$.

I know it is reflexive. I wonder how to show $\mathcal{O}_{X}(D)$ is a  rank 1  sheaf (this is called divisoral sheaf). Notice that by Hartshorne Ex 6.10 (p148), we need to show

$$\text{  }\mathcal{O}_X(D)_\eta\simeq \mathcal{O}_{X, \eta}\simeq K(X)$$

for the generic point $\eta$ of $X$. Here, $K(X)$ denotes the function field.

I can't see how to show this equality above.

Many thanks.

Comment: If you're working out of Hartshorne, why not use the results contained in chapter II section 6? Corollary 6.16 should give you what you need.

Comment: You need some additional assumptions. Not all divisors are locally principal, so $O_X(D)$ might not always be invertible. See 14.2.H in Vakil's Foundations of Algebraic Geometry

Comment: @DavidLui, I didn't say it is invertible.

Comment: Let $L\in Pic(X)$ be an invertible sheaf. Hence if $\eta$ is the generic point in $X$ we get

$$L_{\eta} \cong \mathcal{O}_{U,\eta} \cong B_{\eta} \cong K(B) \cong K(X).$$

For any point $x\in U \subseteq X$ there is are isomorphisms

$$\mathcal{O}_{X,x} :=\lim_{x\in U}\mathcal{O}_X(U) \cong lim_{x\in V}\mathcal{O}_U(V) \cong \mathcal{O}_{U,x},$$
hence for the generic point $\eta \in X$ you get

$$K(A):=K(X):=\mathcal{O}_{X,\eta} \cong \mathcal{O}_{U,\eta}\cong K(B).$$

Comment: @Steve : There is a direct proof in Hartshorne that for any Weil divisor $D$ (with appropriate conditions on $X$), there is an invertible sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X(D)$ corresponding to $D$, and this proof does not use "divisorial sheaves". The proof is "straight forward" and you find all details in HH.

Answer (score 1):

X is smooth outside a codimension $\geq 2$ locus $Z$, so $\mathcal{O}(D)$ is just an invertible sheaf on $X-Z$ and has rank 1.